# How to minimize media queries repeated class name?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I have written the media query for different resolutions, but changing only a particular property. I feel that this is repetitive.

```
@media (min-width: 325px) and (max-width: 420px) { 
    .hero-banner{
        height: 870px;
        background-position: center center !important;
        background-position-y: -120px !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 421px) and (max-width: 480px) { 
    .hero-banner{
        height: 870px;
        background-position: center center !important;
        background-position-y: -180px !important;
    }
  }

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 540px) { 
    .hero-banner{
        height: 870px;
        background-position: center center !important;
        background-position-y: -220px !important;
    }
  }

@media (min-width: 541px) and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .hero-banner{
        height: 870px;
        background-position: center center !important;
        background-position-y: -280px !important;
    }
  }

@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 660px) { 
    .hero-banner{
        height: 870px;
        background-position: center center !important;
        background-position-y: -340px !important;
    }
  }

@media (min-width: 661px) and (max-width: 720px) { 
    .hero-banner{
        height: 870px;
        background-position: center center !important;
        background-position-y: -400px !important;
    }
  }

@media (min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 767px) { 
    .hero-banner{
        height: 870px;
        background-position: center center !important;
        background-position-y: -460px !important;
    }
  }
```

In the above code only ***background-position-y*** is changing in all media queries. Is there any way I can simplify this so that the code looks much cleaner. Ur help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: In the media queries, you only need to have what is specific to each `background-position-y` since the rest is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking into javascript `matchMedia`

You can create an array of objects which includes the width and the style value

```
const info = [
  {
    width: 720,
    style: -120
  },
  {
    width: 480,
    style: -180
  }
]
```

And then loop over it to set the css value

```
info.forEach(obj => {
   let i = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${obj.width}px)`)
   if(i.matches){
      document.getElementById("hero").style.backgroundPositionY = obj.style
   }
})
```

More information on this :
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp

Comment: Hey L, this should be a comment. But since you are not able to comment with less rep, I recommend expanding your answer with an example.

Comment: yes i wanted to comment, anyways i will expand it thanks :)